# How to set default text for a Tkinter Entry widget

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, user-interface, tkinter

How do I set the default text for a Tkinter Entry widget in the constructor?  I checked the documentation, but I do not see a something like a `"string="` option to set in the constructor?

There is a similar answer out there for using tables and lists, but this is for a simple Entry widget.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Use [`Entry.insert`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm#Tkinter.Entry.insert-method). For example:

```
try:
    from tkinter import *  # Python 3.x
except Import Error:
    from Tkinter import *  # Python 2.x

root = Tk()
e = Entry(root)
e.insert(END, 'default text')
e.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Or use [`textvariable`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm#Tkinter.Entry.config-method) option:

```
try:
    from tkinter import *  # Python 3.x
except Import Error:
    from Tkinter import *  # Python 2.x

root = Tk()
v = StringVar(root, value='default text')
e = Entry(root, textvariable=v)
e.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: what is the significance of END in e.insert?

Comment: @sky_bird, `END` denote putting the new string at the end of the entry widget. If there's no string there, it doesn't matter whether you specify `0` or `END`.

Comment: @meatspace, I made the codes run in both Python 2.x / Python 3.x.

Comment: To be honest it's really inconsistent of Tkinter developers not to allow using of e = Entry(root, text='default text') constructor, as they already do with Label etc.

Comment: @AnatolyAlekseev I agree. I've noticed Tkinter does a lot of simple stuff in contrived, unintuitive ways, often that seem to be targeted mainly toward certain types of use cases, and often that's the only way to do that thing.

Answer (score 4):

For me,

```
Entry.insert(END, 'your text')
```

didn't worked.

I used `Entry.insert(-1, 'your text')`.

Thanks.

Comment: If you did e.g. `import tkinter as tk` then you would use `tk.END`. If you use `from tkinter import *`, then simply `END` should work.