# default input value of the tkinter python guide

Tags: user-interface, tkinter, default

everyone, i am using the tkinter to develop a gui, how can i set a default value of the  parameters when i design a input text label? Here is peice of my code, i really appreacite for your help.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVjlJ.png)
[image]

when I use a solution like below: [How to set default text for a Tkinter Entry widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20125967/how-to-set-default-text-for-a-tkinter-entry-widget), it will create a window which is not i want, i need a default value in the text label
[image]
[image]

Comment: Here is link https://www.askpython.com/python-modules/tkinter/stringvar-with-examples